# How do I use JQuery to disable a submit button?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So that it's no longer clickable.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Set the disabled attribute.

`$("#buttonID").attr("disabled", "disabled");`

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't that be

```
$("#buttonID").attr("disabled", true);
```

?

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#buttonID").attr("disabled", "disabled");
```